# Haskell return position of searched item

Tags: haskell

I have the following Haskell code, which returns the an instance of the requested element from the list (just the first instance) or returns 0 if the element is not present. I am trying to return the position of the element in the list instead but don't know how to (I am very new to programming).

e.g. 'm' 'some' is returning m but I want it to return 3.

```
findMe x [] = 0
findMe x (y:ys) = if x == y
                        then x
                        else findMe x ys
```

Comment: FYI there is the function `findIndex` for that, in the `Data.List` module.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. If `0` is returned because element not present, I assume that it is `1` index start.

```
findMe x list = findMeP list 1
  where
    findMeP [] _ = 0
    findMeP (y:ys) n
      | x == y    = n
      | otherwise = findMeP ys (n + 1)
```

As a demo, take a look at [this](https://ideone.com/qDJRPm).

Answer (score 3):

Although the previous answer is correct, here is a solution that I'd prefer since it makes use of basic building blocks from the base library and avoids explicit recursion.

```
import Data.List (find) {- for find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a -}

findMe :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe (Int, a)
findMe x = find ((== x).snd) . zip [1..]
```

The function returns both the element and its index, counting from **zero**, wrapped in a `Maybe` type. If the element is not found, `Nothing` is returned.

To extract the element or the index alone one can map the `fst` and `snd` functions over the `Maybe` result:

```
findMeIndex = fmap fst . findMe
findMeElem  = fmap snd . findMe
```

Example:

```
findMe 'c' ['a','b','c','d'] == Just (2,'c')
findMe 'z' ['a','b','c','d'] == Nothing

findMeIndex 'c' ['a','b','c','d'] == Just 2
findMeIndex 'z' ['a','b','c','d'] == Nothing
```

If you need to start counting from `1`, you can replace `[0..]` with `[1..]`. In either case, wrapping the result in a `Maybe` is preferred to returning some special value signaling the absence of the element (say `-1` or `0`), because then the user cannot ever mistake to interpret your result. For example, if you count from `1` and return `0` on failure, and someone uses your function erroneously thinking that you count from `0`, they may interpret a failure as if the element was found at the first position. Here instead, the user is forced to handle the failure case explicitly.

The function works as follows. `zip [0..]` produces a list of pairs coupling each element with its index, starting from zero (`[0..]` is the infinite list `[0,1,2,3,..]`). Then, `find` scans the list (in exactly the same way as OP's original code), returning the first element for which the function `((== x).snd)` returns `True`, wrapped in a `Maybe` type, if found, or `Nothing` otherwise. Which element does `find` look for? Remember that `find` is fed with a list of *pairs*. So by composing the `snd` function with `(== x)` we find the pair whose second component is equal to `x`